# Set value on dropdownlist OnRowEditing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having a dropdownlist inside a gridview. I wan't the value in the DDL to be the same in edit mode as in view mode, when the gridview get into edit mode the value of DDL set's to the first value be default.

I have tried to get the value before filling and binding the gridview for edit mode but then I get null (nFolderId). And when I try the nFolderId snippet after binding I get the default value (meaning first value).

So how can I get the DDL value to stay from view mode in to edit mode?

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    var nFolderId = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownListFolders1")).SelectedValue);
    FillGridView();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="strPositionId,tmVaRPosition,nFoldersId"
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="gridviewGridlinesSkin" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_CancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
            EmptyDataText="No positions found" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDatabound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit" CommandName="Edit"
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_edit.gif" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_delete.gif" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("strPositionName", "return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this entry {0}?\");") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibUpdate" runat="server" AlternateText="Update" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_ok.gif" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibCancel" runat="server" AlternateText="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_cancel.gif" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strFolderName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList ID="DropDownListFolders1" Width="141px" runat="server"
                                SkinID="BCdropdownlistSkin"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Q. So, the dropdown looks and has the same experience in both modes - view mode and edit mode?

Comment: @deostroll In view mode it's just a label* showing the value

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of SelectedValue

```
<div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dd" HeaderText="dd" SortExpression="dd" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ddd" SortExpression="ddd">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ddd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ddd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cate" SortExpression="cate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource12" DataTextField="cate" DataValueField="id"
                    SelectedValue="<%# Bind('cate') %>">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource12" runat="server"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [cate]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [View_1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       <br />
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"
               style="height: 26px" />
```